# Extract character till last letter

Tags: r

I want to extract from one point to till last character

variable x

```
sdfsfsgfg
sdfdfdftgtgtgt
dfkdsksdnkfjnsk
```

I want to extract from character 5 to last

I want to use substr but not sure how to specify till last. See below code

```
substr(x,5,)
```

Comment: Probably you are looking for `nchar()`.

Comment: Or use `substring(x, 5)`